# What is this unusual fruit seedling?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, seedlings

I planted some fruit seeds last year, but I cannot recall whether they were mangosteen, pomelo, pomegranate, plum or something else.

I tried to compare the leaves of against some online images but I am still confused as what this seedling could be.

*Click on photo for full size*
[image: Tropical Fruit Seedling]

Comment: Are the species you mentioned the only ones you planted?

Comment: Yep, they are the only seeds I could have planted in that particular area. I am not sure if the Australian pomelo is meant to look different to the Chinese pomelo. I have grown the Chinese pomelo in China many years ago, and it definitely does not look like this. However, when I scrunch up the leaves, it has a citrus smell.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that this is a pomegranate seedling. If it's not that, it must be something you didn't plant.

This does not readily appear to be any of the fruits listed in your question. It may be pomegranate, if the leaves are extremely sub-opposite. The leaf shape, margin, color, size, and pubescence fit with pomegranate. It could be a weed, or a volunteer species that you didn't mean to plant, or may have been planted by something else.

Here are the major points on why this isn't on the list you gave:

- **[Mangosteen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_mangosteen):** [The leaves are placed opposite each other](https://www.hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/morton/mangosteen.html). On your plant the leaves appear [alternate](http://www.amnh.org/learn/biodiversity_counts/ident_help/Parts_Plants/leaf_arrangment.htm), and circle the seedling.
- **[Pomelo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomelo):** [These have winged petioles](http://eol.org/pages/488254/details) [(see photo](https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4122/4743672308_0ecc31aede_z.jpg)), which are unapparent on your plant.
- **[Pomegranate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomegranate):** [The leaves are placed opposite (or sub-opposite) each other.](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/mg056) Your plant appears to have [alternate](http://www.amnh.org/learn/biodiversity_counts/ident_help/Parts_Plants/leaf_arrangment.htm) leaves. This is only possibility I see here. The leaf arrangement might be extremely sub-opposite.
- **[Plum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plum):** [have leaves with serrated margins, and are pubescent.](http://www.ehow.com/how_6758945_identify-plum-tree-leaves.html) Your seedling has [entire leaf margins](http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/nworc/files/agriculture/leafid_margin/leafid_margin_print.html), and the leaves are [glabrous](http://en.difain.com/gardening/glabrous.html).

Comment: I have a Pomelo seedling at home right now, and the winged petioles are not there. I am certain it is a Pomelo seedling, because those are the only seeds I planted. I suspect the petioles develop when the plant is a bit more mature, so I wouldn't rule that one out. My seedling only has 4 leaves at this point, so I can't really compare to the seedling in the pic above otherwise.

Comment: @michelle can you post a link to a pic of your seedling?

Comment: Yes! Actually, I just noticed that its newest leaf has developed the wing. How exciting! As you can see from the photo, the first 4 leaves had no wings. The OPs plant has far more leaves than mine, so I'd concur - not a pomelo. http://flic.kr/p/oFi5mT

Comment: @michelle Thank you. Nice lookin' plant. I was also thinking that it isn't pomelo. I think it might be pomegranate.